# How select rows fully completed in IN-query?

Tags: mysql

We have a table with two columns - `art_id` and `cat_id`.
We need to select rows WHERE `cat_id` = 12, 13, 15

I tried to do something:

```
SELECT art_id 
FROM table 
WHERE cat_id IN (12,13,15) 
GROUP BY art_id 
HAVING COUNT(cat_id) > 2
```

but this selection also select art_id = 4 AND 9.

[image: table example]

**Expected Output:**

```
art_id = 1 and 7
```

Comment: Your query should return only `1, 7` result set, are you sure this is the complete data you posted here?

Comment: @Shaharyar, yes. My query in description (example query as i think) is wrong.

Comment: check this one http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/45512/how-do-i-select-items-from-a-table-where-a-single-column-must-contain-two-or-mo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you do not have know beforehand the art_ids, perhaps this?

```
SELECT art_id, GROUP_CONCAT(cat_id SEPARATOR ',') as concatenated
FROM table
GROUP BY art_id
HAVING concatenated = '12,13,15'
```

If the sequence in each group can be different. E.g. 13,12,15 then you'll need to sort the combinations too.

```
SELECT art_id, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT cat_id ORDER BY cat_id ASC SEPARATOR ',') AS concatenated
FROM table
GROUP BY art_id
HAVING concatenated = '12,13,15'
```

Comment: Thank you for idea!

Comment: It works if you want art-id 1 with only the three values 12,13,15.  It doesn't work if you want art-id 1 when you have other value too (eg. add INSERT INTO T1 VALUES (1,17) to your sample data)

Comment: Yup, that is indeed a constraint. But that seems to be the intention of the original query -> where it exactly matches. Extrapolating from there, perhaps if (1,17) is included, then 1 is not returned?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will work for you

```
SELECT art_id 
FROM table 
WHERE cat_id IN (12,13,15) 
AND (art_id = 4 OR art_id = 7) 
GROUP BY art_id 
HAVING COUNT(cat_id) > 2
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this code"? A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way,
not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO that may find this question and be reading your answer.

Comment: Talk about fixing the election in your favour!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, but it works only if you haven't art_id, cat_id repetition eg: it doesn't work if you add in your sample data `INSERT INTO T1 VALUES (9,15)` two times

```
 SELECT DISTINCT T1.art_id
 FROM T1
 INNER JOIN (SELECT art_id, COUNT(*) AS RC
             FROM T1
             WHERE CAT_ID IN (12,13,15)
             GROUP BY art_id) X ON T1.art_id = X.art_id
 WHERE X.RC>2
```

Output:

```
art_id
-----------
1
7
```